# ASP.Net Web Api Controller methods syntax using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've built some RESTful web service methods.

I have generated an entity framework controller for a table in a linked database.

The default get methods work fine, but I'm inexperienced with using put or post to update the table in the database.

These are my working GET methods and the PUT method I am having trouble with.

I want to be able perform PUT like this: http://localhost:52226/api/users/kevy?Name=kevin&StudyLang=spanish&NativeLang=english

As you can see with 4 parameters. I'm pretty awful and don't know what to change in these methods to make a url like that that adds a row in the database table with the given parameters. I have not edited the webapiconfig.cs file. It is the default. I do not know how to edit it, if I even need to. I have not included error messages because I don't really know what I'm doing and just screwing around.

Code from the controller class. I have written some random text in the put method:

```
namespace QuizLang.Controllers
{
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private quizlangEntities db = new quizlangEntities();


    private ActionResult View()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    // GET: api/Users
    public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return db.Users;
    }

    // GET: api/Users/id
    [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(string id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(user);
    }

    // PUT: api/Users/5

    // THIS IS THE METHOD I WANT TO FIX

    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutUser(string id, string name, string nativeLang, string studyLang, string grade)
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        //no fucking clue what this does
        //if (id != user.Id)
        //{
        //  return BadRequest();
        //}

        User user = new User
        {
            Id = id,
            Name = name,
            NativeLang = nativeLang,
            StudyLang = studyLang,
            Grade = grade,

            // …
        };




       // db.Users.Add(user);
        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;


        try
        {

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!UserExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify HTTP method for Web API action:

```
[HttpPut]
public void PutUser(string id, string name, string nativeLang, string studyLang, string grade)
```

Comment: Oh, is it really as simple as adding that to the controller?

Comment: @Cammers not to the controller but to action method.

Comment: @Andrie I'm sorry, but I still am not sure how to use that line of code. Any chance you can copy an example inside an action method, as I interpret it?

Comment: @Cammers just put `[HttpPut]` attribute over your `PutUser` method and it will be accepting PUT HTTP requests.